# Why is C# Threading not woking on multiple cores?

Tags: c#, multithreading

my code is a bit complex, but the core is starting threads like this:

```
Thread task = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(x => { ThreadReturn = BuildChildNodes(x); }));
task.Start((NodeParameters)tasks[0]);
```

it should work. but when i check my CPU usage i get barely 10%. so i do assume it's just using one core. barely.

ThreadReturn btw is a value i use a setter on, to have some kind of event, when the thread is ready:

```
public object ThreadReturn
        {
            set
            {
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    NodeReturn result = (NodeReturn)value;
                    if (result.states.Count == 0) return;
                    Content[result.level + 1].AddRange(result.states);
                    if (result.level + 1 >= MaxDepth) return;
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.states.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Thread newTask = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(x => ThreadReturn = BuildChildNodes(x)));
                        NodeParameters param = new NodeParameters()
                        {
                            level = result.level + 1,
                            node = Content[result.level + 1].Count - (i + 1),
                            turn = SkipOpponent ? StartTurn : !result.turn
                        };
                        if (tasks.Count > 100)
                            unstarted.Add(param);
                        else
                        {
                            newTask.Start(param);
                            tasks.Add(newTask);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i got some crazy error about mark stack overflow so i limited the maximum number of parallel tasks with putting them into a second list...
i'm not firm in multithreading so this code is a little bit messy... maybe you can show me a better way which actually uses my cores.

btw: **it's not the locks fault. i tried without before. -> same result**

Edit: this is my code before i went to the Threading class. i find it more suitable:

```
Content.Clear();
        Content.Add(new List<T> { Root });
        for (var i = 0; i < maxDepth; i++)
            Content.Add(new List<T>());
        Task<object> firstTask = new Task<object>(x => BuildChildNodes(x), (new NodeParameters() { level = 0, node = 0, turn = Turn }));
        firstTask.Start();
        tasks.Add(firstTask);
        while (tasks.Count > 0 && Content.Last().Count == 0)
        {
            Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
            for (int task = tasks.Count - 1; task >= 0; task--)
            {
                if (tasks[task].IsCompleted)
                {
                    NodeReturn result = (NodeReturn)tasks[task].Result;
                    tasks.RemoveAt(task);
                    Content[result.level + 1].AddRange(result.states);
                    if (result.level + 1 >= maxDepth) continue;
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.states.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Task<object> newTask = new Task<object>(x => BuildChildNodes(x), (object)new NodeParameters() { level = result.level + 1, node = Content[result.level + 1].Count - (i + 1), turn = SkipOpponent ? Turn : !result.turn });
                        newTask.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In every state i'm calculating children and in my main thread i put them into my state tree while waiting for the tasks to finish. please assume i'd actually use the return value of waitany, i did a git reset and now... welll... it's gone^^

Edit:
Okay i don't know what exactly i did wrong but... in general everything was a total mess. i now implemented the deep construction method and maybe because there's much less... "traffic" now my whole code runs in 200ms. so... thanks for this!

i don't know if i should delete this question hence stupidity or if you guys want to post answers so i can rate them postive, you really helped me a lot :)

Comment: Please do not show your code as a picture. Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block.

Comment: sorry... i just don't like that extra space i have to manually remove...

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of work to be doing inside a `set` accessor.  And the spawned `Thread` invokes the `set` accessor of the same property?

Comment: yep that was the plan. so it gets called everytime a thread finishs. the plan is that the input parameters determine when no more threads get spawned. i also have a main loop assuring that it continues when there are no more threads working... but you're right somehow i have a awful feel XD

Comment: @KyoshiroKokujouObscuritas Select multiple lines, Ctrl+K. Or alt+shift+select in Visual Studio editor.

Comment: btw i worked with tasks before. then i noticed that just Threads are real multithreading and tasks are just async stuff... for constructing a state tree with 100.000 states you need multithreading

Comment: All threads are locking on the same lock in the `ThreadReturn` property, so effectively they are running sequentially. Rather than firing off threads manually like that, you should use other tools to trigger and synchronize them like the TPL and use better algorithms.

Comment: i don't do any reading ... i mean right now there's not even much calculating. i'm just setting some values. i'm just doing it 100.000 times ^^

Comment: okay so let me assure that: That threading stuff DOES multithreading? i'm just messing my code up? because i'm never really sure if what i'm doing is parallel or async or whatever XD 
is Threading.Tasks also real parallel or as i assumed just async too?

Comment: Yes, threading stuff does multithreading. Your code sample is complicated enough that it's difficult to reason through. Try simplifying it down to something that we could run on our own machines, so we can replicate the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: yeah i guess i'll use another approach. right now i'm gonna remodel it so i'll construct deep instead of broad. in my root state there are 8 possible following states, so i could just construct them as deep as they go and let those 8 deep constructions run parallel. should work

Comment: As s side note, writing `Thread task = new Thread()` is like writing `Apple orange = new Apple()`. Extremely confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disregarding all the other issues you have here, essentially your `lock` ruins the show.

What you are saying is, hey random person go and do some stuff! just make sure you don't do it at the same time as anyone else (`lock`), you could have 1000 threads, but only one thread is going to be active at one time on one core, hence your results.

Here are some other thoughts.

1. Get the gunk out of the *setter*, this would fail any sane code review.
2. Use *Tasks* instead of `Thread`.
3. Thinking about what needs *thread safety*, and elegantly `lock` only what needs it, Take a look at the [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.8) for dealing with numeric atomic manipulation
4. Take a look at the [concurrent collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) you may get more mileage out of this
5. Simplify your code.

I can't give any more advice as it's just about impossible to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: my not does not ruin anything. as stated above i've already tested it without lock. i just used the lock since some problems occured i used this to test if they were because of the multithreading or because i overlooked something in my code. usually i want to build my code so that no kind of lock is neccessary, thats why i'm passing "serialized" object values.

second: Tasks are real multithreading too? i never get if they actually do the multithreading or just async stuff.

Comment: hey, but those concurrenct collections could be of help, that's a nice find! another thing... why are computers so slow?! i'lll definitely open another question for this but... i mean processors are GHz, i have "just" 100.000 operations. in those iterations i'm not even calculating now, still it takes a minute without multithreading. and multithreading is more like x/core_count in the best case, isn't it?

Comment: @KyoshiroKokujouObscuritas: Processor speed is not the only thing at play. For example, [memory access takes orders of magnitude longer than a CPU cycle](https://www.prowesscorp.com/computer-latency-at-a-human-scale/). The fact that your CPU is hardly seeing any activity even when multithreading probably has more to do with `BuildChildNodes` doing things that cause the CPU to wait for data to come in before it can perform actual calculations. Your 100,000 "operations" do not equate to the same thing as the billion "operations" that a 1GHz processor can perform in a second.

Comment: yeah right now i'm desparately trying to reduce my costs. right now at least i get it in 800ms, but since my game has a random field i can't precalculate. worst case is building a 8!^2 state tree - impossible. so now i cut off the opponent turns. but still 800ms per turn are pretty awful. especially till i'm not even half done with my calculations per turn.

well with my new approach i could reduce the runtime to something that at least gives me hope... no chance for an android implementation but yeah ^^